# Starting ArcMap says system clock has been set back more than 24 hours?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, windows-7, arcgis-license-manager

In order to test my log4net logging daily, I changed my clock to be 2 days later.

When I changed back the clock to normal, I cannot start ArcMap, I get a message:

> The system clock has been set back more than 24 hours

I found a possible [solution provided by Esri](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/24575), but it not work.

Is there another solution for it?

I am using Wndows 7 and ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Comment: You need to contact ESRI Support services. This problem is due to the License Server noticing the change of time. It is done to prevent people form using the software beyond the license period. They will probably give you a new license file.

Comment: Thank you  Devdatta Tengshe, you prevent me from wasting time on it.

Comment: I just experienced this on ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.  ESRI support just had me delete all the files in the "C:\ProgramData\FLEXnet" directory.  Then I was able to reauthorize my license.

Comment: Thanks @TimSexton, your solution solved this problem for me, without having to contact support.  I have a trial version and got the error when my asus mistakenly set the system clock way in the future, and then corrected itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest that you contact ESRI Support services.

This problem is due to the License Server noticing the change of time. It is done to prevent people form using the software beyond the license period.

They will probably give you a new license file.

Answer (score 1):

More information about the comment made by @Tim Sexton can be found here:
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011660

This is an Esri technical support article regarding:
How To: Clear or delete trusted storage for concurrent-use and single-use licenses